# java: avoid instanceof and + better solution for code design

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

i need help with designing my code.
assume i got an interface that represents a metadata of fields

```
public interface FieldDefinition {
   boolean validate(Object value)
   FieldTypeDefinition getFieldTypeDefinition()
}
```

and classes that implement this interface(i'm not writing here all the context such as properties i.e),

```
public class SomeFieldDefinition implements FieldDefinition {
    @Override
    public boolean validate(Object value) {
        // some general validation logic
    }
    @Override
    public FieldTypeDefinition getFieldTypeDefinition() {
        // return NumericFieldTypeDefinition or StringFieldTypeDefinition
    }
}

public class SomeFieldDefinition2 implements FieldDefinition {
    @Override
    public boolean validate(Object value) {
        // some general validation logic
    }
    @Override
    public FieldTypeDefinition getFieldTypeDefinition() {
        // return NumericFieldTypeDefinition or StringFieldTypeDefinition
    }
}
```

now, FieldTypeDefinition is also an interface

```
public interface FieldTypeDefinition {
    public String getTypeName();
    boolean validate(FieldDefinition fieldDefinition,Object value);
}
```

and i have concrete classes that implements it

```
public class StringFieldTypeDefinition implements FieldTypeDefinition {
    @Override
    public String getTypeName() {
        return "String";
    }
    @Override
    public boolean validate(FieldDefinition fieldDefinition, Object value) {
        // some specific field of type string validations by fieldDefinition type
    }
}
public class NumericFieldTypeDefinition implements FieldTypeDefinition {
    @Override
    public String getTypeName() {
        return "Number";
    }
    @Override
    public boolean validate(FieldDefinition fieldDefinition, Object value) {
        // some specific field of type number validations by fieldDefinition type
    }
}
```

now, when i want to do some validation on fields, i want to have general validations, and specific validation by the field type.
so assume i'm invoking the method validate on SomeFieldDefinition2 with a String parameter the method will look like this:

```
public boolean validate(Object value) {
    // some general validation logic
    getFieldTypeDefinition().validate(this, value); // getFieldTypeDefinition() returns StringFieldTypeDefinition
}
```

and this causes me a problem because in validate method of **StringFieldTypeDefinition** class i need to check the instance of fieldDefinition parameter, and by its value, make the suitable validation logic, 
because in each FieldDefinition type class i have a different logic and metadata.

is there a better way of designing my code? 
i hope my question is understandable.

Comment: Offtopic: ***FieldDefinition*** depends of ***FieldTypeDefinition*** which depends of ***FieldDefinition***... are you aware of that circular dependency?

Comment: i'm, but how can i validate the field value without its metadata?

Comment: can you give us a little more context on what the design is trying to accomplish? maybe give a short example of what needs to be validated.

Comment: If you're looking to optimize your code, you might be more successful on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)